# Передача v-model в v-html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как сделать v-model реактивным при передаче в v-html

```
<div id="app">

  <div v-html="test"></div>
  {{ message }}
```

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'test',
    test: '<input type="text" v-model="message">'
  }
})
```

Comment: `v-html` вставляет обычный html и не компилирует как шаблон vue. Вынесите `test` в отдельный компонент и передайте `message` c помощью `props`

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен компонент [v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template)

Comment: "Выглядит нормально", но имхо небольшой пример топикстартеру не помешал бы. - из очереди проверок.